# How to apply JQuery selector to Wicket ModalWindow

Tags: java, jquery, wicket

I'm using one of the spiffy new show-your-password-single-char JQuery hacks, which I can apply to my all password fields on a page with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready( function() {
    $('input:password').dPassword();
  });
</script>
```

But my change password dialog is rendered in a Wicket ModalWindow,

```
final ModalWindow window = new ModalWindow("change-password-panel");
final PasswordChangePanel panel = new PasswordChangePanel(window, myPasswordValidator);
window.setContent(panel);
add(window);
add(new AjaxFallbackLink<String>("change-password") {
    @Override public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        window.show(target);
    }});
```

so it isn't there on document.ready.

How can I arrange to re-run the JQuery selector when my ModalWindow has been shown?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try sending back some JS to run upon completion of the AJAX call:

```
add(new AjaxFallbackLink<String>("change-password") {
    @Override 
    public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        target.appendJavascript("$('input:password').dPassword();")
        window.show(target);
    }
});
```

It's better to restrict the scope of the selector to just your modal window, but I'd need to see the code to be able to do that. ;)

Comment: Excellent - I thought that I'd tried this, but on reflection I evidently hadn't as it does the trick. Thanks, and please vote up the question if you thought it was useful.

Comment: You know, I just had another thought, too.  You could probably modify the code like so : `"$('#" + window.getMarkupId() + " input:password').dPassword();"` as a way of constraining the selector.